# Misplaced footer in UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, footer

I have a plain UITableView in an IOS IPad app. Nothing magic in it, just the same as I have used million times before: implement datasource and delegate methods in a very trivial way.

But noes there is a very strange behavior: footer of UITableView gets misplaced, it floats over the cells. Please, see the attached screenshot (I have marked the misplaced footer by an arrow):

[image]

As you can see, **footer** floats well before/above the last cell, **not at the bottom of the list. There is one more cell after.**

The footer is nothing more than this:

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section{
return @"SomeFooter";}
```

This problem comes, when the number of cells are more, than the number of cells can fit to the screen.

Any help is appreciated, thanks very much!

Comment: Isn't it the same thing like headers, where in plain style tableview the headers don't scroll off the tableview? Looks like you have plain style and some bottom inset.

Comment: set your footer background colour to white..

Comment: It is good, that it don'ts scroll of. The problem, it is at wrong position, not at the bottom of the table. Yes, it is plain.

Comment: Why should I change it to white? Then it would appear at the end of the list? Thanks your comments

Comment: Check if your tableview's frame is at the right dimensions and goes up to the toolbar.

Comment: Yes it is. And as you can see cells at the top and at the bottom are at the right places, they fit the screen between the navigation bar and the bottom bar. Thanks.

Comment: It is aligned to the bottom layout guide by value 0.

Comment: zbMax, you put me to the right direction, if you answer it, I will accept your answer. I changed layout constraints: bottom layout guide did not work properly in my case, i changed it to align to the bottom to the map next to it. I feel some kind of hack it, but works at least. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any code to do it and make it behave the way you want. Just get rid of `titleForFooterInSection` and simply drag a UIView in storyboard at the bottom of your UITableView. You can then format that however you please and it will not stick to the bottom as footer headers do by default.

Comment: Yes, it could be easy, but why, if there is a built in footer that behaved correctly so far.

Comment: Because when you add a header to the footer it will stick to the edge of the table just like a section header will stick to the table when you scroll up.